# How do I define new command to give me a section called Bibliograpy?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

I'm not an expert in latex. I am using a template with the following new command:

```
% we use \prefix@<level> only if it is defined
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
% define \prefix@section
\newcommand\prefix@section{Exercise \thesection }
```

This basically makes it so that when I use `\section{}` instead of writing "Section 1: " it writes "Exercise 1".

However I now want to add, after a couple of these sections, a section called "Bibliography", WITH NO NUMBER.

So I tried manipulating the code above (again, I'm not an expert) in the following way:

```
% we use \prefix@<level> only if it is defined
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
% define \prefix@section
\newcommand\prefix@section{Exercise \thesection }


\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
% define \prefix@section
\newcommand\prefix@subsection{Bibliography \thesection }
```

Basically I've added the same code, changed Exercise to Bibliography and then section to subsection (as I tried with section and it said it was already defined). But if I use `\subsection{}` it gives me "Bibliography 2". How do I get just "Bibliography"?

**Edit: Minimal Working Example**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black}

\makeatletter
% we use \prefix@<level> only if it is defined
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
% define \prefix@section
\newcommand\prefix@section{Exercise \thesection }


\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
% define \prefix@section
\newcommand\prefix@subsection{Bibliography }
\makeatother
\title{Homework}

\author{My Name}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section{ } 
#First Exercise

\section{ }
#Another Exercise

\subsection{}
[1]Wikipedia \textit{Gibbs Phenomenon} Available: \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon} 




\end{document}
```

Comment: Just remove the `\thesection`.

Comment: @TeXnician thank you, it worked! However, since I am using subsections,  the fontsize is smaller. How do I make it so that it's the same size of the other sections?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `\section*` or something? However, please post a MWE so that we can help you better (e.g. for formatting).

Comment: @TeXnician I'll try now. Anyway, I'm not sure what an MWE is, but I'm using Overleaf.com, so I don't really have latex downloaded on my laptop!

Comment: A minimal working example shows a compilable (!) code (with documentclass etc.) that produces the error.

Comment: I don't recommend changing a template, which is something for experienced users only. It also is critical due to file lincencess and ownership. Never a good idea to change a file you don't own and are (maybe) no allowed to change.

Comment: @Johannes_B  what do you reccommend instead? I would just like to have all the sections called "Exercise [insert exercise number]" and then the last section called "Bibliography"

Comment: @Okay, I will provide it!

Comment: Try `\section*{Bibliography}` as was suggested above.

Comment: There is a difference between the user interface a template user uses, and the code that provides that user interface, which is much more complex.  You are trying to change that complex code instead of simply using the simple code. A trap many template users fall for, because a template wasn't what they were looking for due a lack of proper communication.

Comment: @Johannes_B yes what you say sounds right. So does `\section*{}` give me a section without "Section [number of section]" or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `\section*{}` works. But as you seem to be a LaTeX beginner I would recommend you reading some of the free beginner guides on the internet (especially the sections about sectioning).

And if I could give you a recommendation: Replace `\thesection` with `\thesection\` (with space at the end) or even `\thesection\quad`, because else the spacing is very unsatisfactory (e.g. "1TEST").

[image: sec]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% we use \prefix@<level> only if it is defined
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
% define \prefix@section
\newcommand\prefix@section{Exercise \thesection }


\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
% define \prefix@section
\newcommand\prefix@subsection{Bibliography }
\makeatother
\title{Homework}

\author{My Name}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section{TEST} 
This is a test

\section{ASDF}
This is a test

\section*{Bibliography}
[1]Wikipedia \textit{Gibbs Phenomenon} Available: \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon} 


\end{document}
```